# Using \value and \arabic to label sections

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I'm trying to create a document that follows a numbering system of:

1.
1.a
1.a.1
1.a.2
1.b    etc

I've tried to use the commands below to specify which section/subsection should be labelled with arabic and which should be labelled with a value. However it's not worked, and I suspect either I am missing a command needed to combine the two labelling types, or that it cannot be done!

```
   \value{section}
   \arabic{subsection}
   \value{subsubsection}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 9):

`\value` returns an internal register counter suitable for TeX arithmetic and numeric tests, it does not return tokens that may be directly typeset, you want `\arabic` for that.

I think you want:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
```